# no available XVideo adaptor

Tags: video, adapter

I am opening a pdf document containing an embedded video. The video is displayed but there is an accompanying thread of errors?

```
vdpau_avcodec generic error: Xlib is required for VDPAU
xcb_xv vout display error: no available XVideo adaptor
```

What to do?